# Why aren't all the [dependencies] tagged question tagged with dpkg/apt?

Tags: discussion, tags

Supposedly, all dependencies question are about dependencies problems with apt or dpkg, yet, [less than the 50%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dependencies+-apt+-dpkg) (460 out 735 doesn't have it) has either of the tags. Why if every question about dependencies are about either apt or dpkg, doesn't seems to be happening?

I feel that is easier making sure than all apt and dpkg questions have their apt/dpkg tag, instead of having yet-another-tag that only serves to balkanize all the apt/dpkg questions, or that gets misapplied for things that [obviously](https://askubuntu.com/q/539591/169736) [aren't](https://askubuntu.com/q/540520/169736) [apt](https://askubuntu.com/q/532495/169736) or [dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/q/530980/169736) issues, at all. Why do we have an extra tag, when these topics have their own tags?

Comment: You mean like [tag:unity-dash] and [tag:launcher]?

Comment: @Seth err... I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Not all the questions in tagged with dependencies are about package dependencies. I know this isn't the point you're trying to make here, but a fair few of these are just build and runtime library dependencies. In that light, I have edited the description on [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dependencies) so it isn't just about apt or dpkg.

The old description was clearly just too discrete for how the tag is actually being used.

So after this, all the questions that are about apt dependencies, should be tagged with both tags. Or, you know, we can edit war until we all run out of bandwidth.

Comment: "I know this isn't the point you're trying to make here" actually that's exactly the point I'm trying to make here. Why having a tag for things that can happen almost with any software, extremely generic? Is like having an error tag (and you know it's bad), just that in this case is a "special" error.

Comment: It's not extremely generic though. It's a couple of processes with overlapping resolutions.

Comment: Ok, I see where this is going. You are still not seeing my point, and I'm tired of trying to make it see my point everywhere.